# How can check the cart if it contains the element I've select in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm practicing UI Test in https://www.saucedemo.com/   using Cypress, it's a demo e-commerce website.
i log in with standard_user and secret_sauce for password as it's shown in the first page

I want to know how to collect the product's name if it's been chosen so i can be able to check the cart if it contains the right product

my code now is

```
 it("select 2 products", () => {
    cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .pricebar > .btn_primary').click();
    cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .pricebar > .btn_secondary')
    .should("contain","REMOVE")
    cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .pricebar > .btn_primary').click();
    cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .pricebar > .btn_secondary')
    .should("contain","REMOVE")
    cy.get('.fa-layers-counter')
    .should("contain","2")
    });


it("check cart", () => {
    cy.get('path').click();
    cy.get('.subheader').should("contain","Your Cart");
    cy.get('.inventory_item_name').should("have.length",2) 
    .should("contain","Sauce Labs Fleece Jacket");
    cy.get('.inventory_item_price').should("have.length",2) 
    .should('contain',"49.99")
});
```

But as i mentioned above, i want to collect the name if the inventory_item contains the button with text remove how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

See Cypress doc on [invoke command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html#Syntax) and [aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values).

If the name of the inventory-item is on the button, you may use:

```
it("select 2 products", () => {
    cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .pricebar > .btn_primary').click()
        .invoke('val').as('inventoryItemName0');
    cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .pricebar > .btn_secondary')
        .should("contain","REMOVE")
    cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .pricebar > .btn_primary').click()
        .invoke('val').as('inventoryItemName1');
    cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .pricebar > .btn_secondary')
        .should("contain","REMOVE")
    cy.get('.fa-layers-counter')
        .should("contain","2")
});

it("check cart", () => {
    cy.get('path').click();
    cy.get('.subheader').should("contain","Your Cart");
    cy.get('.inventory_item_name').should("have.length", 2).each((element, index) => {
        cy.get("@inventoryItemName" + index).then(name => {
             cy.wrap(element).should("include.text", name);
        });
    });
    cy.get('.inventory_item_price').should("have.length",2) 
        .should('contain',"49.99")
});
```

The argument given to Invoke command depends on whether the inventory-item name is given as a value to the button or as text:

If the html element is like `<button value="name"/>`, use `.invoke('val')`.

Else if like `<button>name</button>`, use `invoke('text')`.

Comment: thanks for answering!! I did it but when i run Cypress ,it shows that it check only the inventoryItemName0 but it doesn't check inventoryItemName1 even if the each command.. how can i fix that?

Comment: Are you saying the each loop only executes once or it executes twice with the same index?